# Can you run training and evalutaion process from a single anaconda prompt?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api, custom-training

I am having trouble evaluating my training process during training a  Tensorflow2 Custom Object Detector. After reading several issues related to this problem I found that evaluation and training should be treated as two separate processes therefore I should use a new anaconda prompt for starting the evaluation job.
I am training on the ssd_mobilenetv2 640x640 version. My pipeline configuration:

```
model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 6
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 640
        width: 640
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: "ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpn_keras"
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      min_depth: 16
      conv_hyperparams {
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 3.9999998989515007e-05
          }
        }
        initializer {
          random_normal_initializer {
            mean: 0.0
            stddev: 0.009999999776482582
          }
        }
        activation: RELU_6
        batch_norm {
          decay: 0.996999979019165
          scale: true
          epsilon: 0.0010000000474974513
        }
      }
      use_depthwise: true
      override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams: true
      fpn {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
        additional_layer_depth: 128
      }
    }
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
        use_matmul_gather: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      weight_shared_convolutional_box_predictor {
        conv_hyperparams {
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 3.9999998989515007e-05
            }
          }
          initializer {
            random_normal_initializer {
              mean: 0.0
              stddev: 0.009999999776482582
            }
          }
          activation: RELU_6
          batch_norm {
            decay: 0.996999979019165
            scale: true
            epsilon: 0.0010000000474974513
          }
        }
        depth: 128
        num_layers_before_predictor: 4
        kernel_size: 3
        class_prediction_bias_init: -4.599999904632568
        share_prediction_tower: true
        use_depthwise: true
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      multiscale_anchor_generator {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
        anchor_scale: 4.0
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        scales_per_octave: 2
      }
    }
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 9.99999993922529e-09
        iou_threshold: 0.6000000238418579
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
        use_static_shapes: false
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    loss {
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid_focal {
          gamma: 2.0
          alpha: 0.25
        }
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    encode_background_as_zeros: true
    normalize_loc_loss_by_codesize: true
    inplace_batchnorm_update: true
    freeze_batchnorm: false
  }
}
train_config {
  batch_size: 4
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  #data_augmentation_options {
    #random_crop_image {
      #min_object_covered: 0.0
      #min_aspect_ratio: 0.75
      #max_aspect_ratio: 3.0
      #min_area: 0.75
      #max_area: 1.0
      #overlap_thresh: 0.0
    #}
  #}
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer {
      learning_rate {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: 0.04999999821186066
          total_steps: 50000
          warmup_learning_rate: 0.0026666000485420227
          warmup_steps: 600
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.8999999761581421
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "pre-trained-models\ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_640x640_coco17_tpu-8\checkpoint\ckpt-0"
  num_steps: 50000
  startup_delay_steps: 0.0
  replicas_to_aggregate: 8
  max_number_of_boxes: 100
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
  fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
}
train_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "annotations/label_map.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "data/train.record"
  }
 
}
eval_config {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
}
eval_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "annotations/label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "data/test.record"
  }
}
```

I have started the training with the command:

```sh
python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=models/my_ssd2_3/ --pipeline_config_path=models/my_ssd2_3/pipeline.config --sample_1_of_n_eval_examples 1 --logtostderr
```

I was hoping that setting the number of evaluation examples will have an effect of starting the evaluation job. In any case I tried running the evaluation in a different terminal window with : `python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=models/my_ssd2_3 --pipeline_config_path=models/my_ssd2_3/pipeline.config --checkpoint_dir=models/my_ssd2_3/ --alsologtostderr`
As soon as starting the evaluation the training job crashes with this error:[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ig2j.png)

The problem I think that I do not have the sufficient hardware:

1. 8GB RAM
2. NVIDIDA GTX960M (2GB RAM)

Could it be a problem that all the input images that I use are 3000x3000, therefore the preprocesser has to load too many information? If so, is there any way to work around it? I would not want to resize all the images before generating TF record file, because I would have to re-label all the images. I clearly lack the insight of how the memory is being allocated during the start of the training process so some details would be much appreciated.

---

A second question is that during monitoring the training on tensorboard the images are displayed with various brightness I tried changing in the model_lib_v2.py file the 627 line to:

```
data= (features[fields.InputDataFields.image]-np.min(features[fields.InputDataFields.image]))/(np.max(features[fields.InputDataFields.image])-np.min(features[fields.InputDataFields.image]))
,
```

According to this solution:https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/9115
Without any luck. Is there a solution to this problem? Also it would be nice if I could monitor there the bounding boxes the modell proposes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some changes to the train_loop function in model_lib.py, you can alternate between training and evaluation in the same application. See the example below.

From what I understand, the Tensorflow Object Detection API is developed with a focus on distributed learning and if you were using mulitple GPUs/TPUs then you could have some devices doing training and other devices doing evaluation. So I suspect the way model_lib.py is implemented currently does not fully support doing training and evaluation on the same device.

I'm not certain the root cause of the error you are seeing, typically I have seen Tensorflow throw OOM errors when there is a memory issue. It may be that how Tensorflow is using CUDA does not support two applications using the same device.

Regarding your second question, I followed the advice [here on the same thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/9115#issuecomment-862003383) and this worked for me. Duplicating the code in the third code block below.  Initially, this did not appear to work for me because I naively updated the file in the Object Detection repository I created, but your application may be using the Object Detection API that is installed in your site-libs, so I would recommend confirming that the file you are changing is the same one being loaded in your import statements.

--

This is outside of the training loop

```py
  ##Set up evaluation data and writer
  eval_config = configs['eval_config']
  eval_input_configs = configs['eval_input_configs']
  eval_input_config = eval_input_configs[0]
  eval_input = strategy.experimental_distribute_dataset(
    inputs.eval_input(
        eval_config=eval_config,
        eval_input_config=eval_input_config,
        model_config=model_config,
        model=detection_model))
  
  summary_writer_eval = tf.compat.v2.summary.create_file_writer(os.path.join(model_dir, 'eval', eval_input_config.name))
```

This is the modified train/evaluation loop. The evaluation happens near the end.

```py
for _ in range(global_step.value(), train_steps, num_steps_per_iteration):
  
  tf.logging.info('Performing Training')
  with summary_writer_train.as_default():
    with tf.compat.v2.summary.record_if(lambda: global_step % num_steps_per_iteration == 0):

      losses_dict = _dist_train_step(train_input_iter)

      time_taken = time.time() - last_step_time
      last_step_time = time.time()
      steps_per_sec = num_steps_per_iteration * 1.0 / time_taken

      tf.compat.v2.summary.scalar(
          'steps_per_sec', steps_per_sec, step=global_step)

      steps_per_sec_list.append(steps_per_sec)

      logged_dict = losses_dict.copy()
      logged_dict['learning_rate'] = learning_rate_fn()

      for key, val in logged_dict.items():
        tf.compat.v2.summary.scalar(key, val, step=global_step)

      if global_step.value() - logged_step >= 0:
        logged_dict_np = {name: value.numpy() for name, value in
                          logged_dict.items()}
        tf.logging.info(
            'Step {} per-step time {:.3f}s'.format(
                global_step.value(), time_taken / num_steps_per_iteration))
        tf.logging.info(pprint.pformat(logged_dict_np, width=40))
        print_gpu_memory_usage()
        logged_step = global_step.value()

      if ((int(global_step.value()) - checkpointed_step) >=
          checkpoint_every_n):
        manager.save()
        checkpointed_step = int(global_step.value())
        
  tf.logging.info('Performing Evaluation')
  with summary_writer_eval.as_default():
    eager_eval_loop(
        detection_model,
        configs,
        eval_input,
        use_tpu=use_tpu,
        global_step=global_step,
        )
```

Fixing image rendering in TensorBoard

```py
if record_summaries:
    imgs = features[fields.InputDataFields.image][:3] 
    imgs = tf.div(tf.subtract(imgs, tf.reduce_min(imgs)), tf.subtract(tf.reduce_max(imgs), tf.reduce_min(imgs)))
    tf.compat.v2.summary.image(name='train_input_images', step=global_step, data=imgs, max_outputs=3)
```

Comment: Thank you I was indeed changing files in the repo I created. Do you suggest these changes to be made to model_lib_v2.py in the reprository my virtual enviroment uses right? Also I only have to make changes in the training loop itself or also copy the section you refered to before the training loop? After I made the changes it returns wit this error massage: "File "C:\Users\Milan\anaconda3\envs\train1\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 689, in train_loop
    with summary_writer_train.as_default():
NameError: name 'summary_writer_train' is not defined" Thank you @Chubbs

Comment: Regarding the error, the code I posted is directional. I didn't track the exact changes I made to model_lib_v2 for this issue. Likely I changed the summary_writer to summary_writer_train to help distinguish it from summary_writer_eval. This is all in the `train_loop` function, but the actual training loop is where that for statement is and the code before that is setup.

Comment: I created a copy of the `model_lib_v2.py` file and put that in the workspace, in the same directory as my `model_main_tf2.py` file. You may need to change the import statement in `model_main_tf2.py` Python prioritizes importing from modules that are in the same directory of the script being run, so this allows you to make changes to model_lib_v2.py without overwriting what is installed in site_libs. The copy in site_libs could get overwritten if you were to pip install the object api again, for example. This also allows you to version the changes as part of your project.

Comment: Reference for import priority: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Comment: Thank you I was able to run the training process and the evaluation at the same time, and I can aslo see the training and evaluation pictures with proper brightness, although their resolution still seem a little bit odd.

Comment: Nice. The Object API has an image resizer preprocessing step (it is configured in pipeline.config) that will reshape the image to the size required by the model, it's possible the resolution issue you are seeing is due to that. It would only impact the training summaries, not the eval summaries. I also think, but haven't confirmed, the recommended fix for the saturation isn't necessarily true to the original saturation, but it shouldn't affect your training data, just the summaries.

If this answered your question, please accept the answer. Thank you!